# Excel Macro to write value based on value of two other columns in row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pickle that I was hoping to get some help with.  I cobbled together a macro the other day following this logic:

If a cell in column B has a particular text, "brand1", and that row has the value "y" in column U, then populate column W of that row with a text string, "sample1".

I had it working the other day, but for some reason it's not working today.  Any ideas or thoughts?  Totally open to the idea of scrapping this macro anyway and using a different one.

```
Sub PromoID()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Brand1") <> 0 Then
    InStr(1, cell.Offset(, 21).Value, "y") <> 0 Then
            cell.Offset(, 23).Value = "sample1"
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume the macro is in the module for the sheet in question as the code makes no refference to a sheet. Any possiblity the code is looking at the wrong sheet when you run it?

Comment: What is the problem that is now occurring? Does it result in an error?

Comment: Yeah, it is in module for the sheet I'm working in.  I should clarify, the macro is running without an error, but it doesn't populate cells that it should be populating with a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not that far from the answer. Keep your eyes peeled for minor errors.

```
Sub PromoID()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Brand1") <> 0 Then
    If InStr(1, cell.Offset(0, 19).Value, "y") <> 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 21).Value = "sample1"
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: My screen resolution is as high as Snoop Dogg in Jamaican afternoon. Sorry if it doesn't show me much.

Comment: That did the trick!  I feel pretty silly for missing that now, and not being able to count the cell offset correctly.  I really appreciate the help!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make everything uppercase. With Ucase()

```
If ucase(InStr(1, cell.Value, "Brand1") ) <> 0 Then ucase(InStr(1, cell.Offset(, 21).Value, "y") ) <> 0 Then cell.Offset(, 23).Value = "sample1"
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately that didn't fix it.

However, that does bring up an interesting note; I thought that maybe it wasn't finding anything with that text because the column where it was looking wasn't formatted correctly.  I've tried formatting it as "text" instead of its default, which is "general".  No dice there either.  Let me know if there's a better way to code that though if it's looking for a text string in a "general" formatted column.

Comment: I think you have to make that range also ucase.  `For Each cell In ucase(Range("B2:B" & lastRow)) ` but I am noob in vbs.  :)